# xfce4-terminal closes without confirmation dialog

Tags: xfce4-terminal

Earlier, when I used to run unity in Ubuntu 14.04 `gnome-terminal` asks conformation dialog **if any process is running in the shell** when I click on close button as follows:

[image: sure to close]

But now I am using `xfce4-terminal` after installing the `xubuntu-desktop` environment in Xubuntu. And one problem is that in spite of processes running inside the terminal, it **closes immediately** while clicking on the close button **instead of** asking by confirmation dialog!

Consider I'm installing packages by `apt-get` and by-mistake if I click on close button then terminal close without confirmation! This does not seem OK.

So, is there any way to enable such type of confirmation dialog in `xfce4-terminal`?

Answer (score 5):

I could not find any such option. The closest you can get is by opening multiple tabs, for which XFCE Terminal does ask for confirmation. The option governing this is `MiscConfirmClose` in `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc` (which was set to `TRUE` by default in my system).

Comment: This option also governs confirmation when a process is running, at least on my system (Debian 11, XFCE 4.14)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it. I just had a look through the available preferences and I don't see anything relevant. I also wouldn't expect it. This kind of confirmation dialogue is, IMO, exceedingly annoying. If I click on something, I clicked on something and I don't want my system to assume I don't know what I'm doing. If I didn't want to close the terminal I wouldn't have clicked on the little X button in the first place. This kind of hand-holding, "the user is an idiot who needs to be protected" is one of the things that annoy me most in the Windows world and I hate seeing it come to Linux.

Anyway, rant over. If you really want this "feature", why not use `gnome-terminal`? There is no reason to use different terminal emulators with different desktop environments. For example, I use `terminator` which is based on `gnome-terminal` in both XFCE and Cinnamon. I have also used it in KDE, in Gnome and in WindowMaker.

Answer (score 1):

You can switch `MiscTabCloseButtons` from TRUE to FALSE in `~/.config/xfce4/terminal/terminalrc`. Then if You wan to close tab, You need to click right mouse button and select "Close tab"

Answer (score 0):

Add `--hold` at the end of xfce4 terminal launcher command

[image]